# RouteLink with Knockoutjs template item properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a template rendering another template via `foreach: viewModel.foos`. On this template I would like to do something like this: `@Html.RouteLink("View", "Foo", new { id = fooId, text = fooName })`. Being `fooId` and `fooName` properties of the view model.

Comment: This will not work this way, remember that KO is used for client-side binding and RouteLink is an html helper that runs on the server-side. A good thing, if not the best, you can do is assign the url to a js variable then build and bind your link (a tag) in KO using that url assigned to a vaiable.

Comment: +1 for making me realize I needed coffee. I think I got it, I will update my question with the raw and unfriendly and `temporary` solution to this.

Comment: If your edit solved your issue then you should have made it an answer and accept it (after a few days of course). In that way others can see how it solved your problem and might help them in the future.

Comment: Move navigation to client is the best approuch if you ask me, there are plenty SPA engines for KO, durandal etc

Comment: @vonv. It was my intention to edit this as a temporary fix, if I couldn't get a better approach I will make the edit as an answer in a couple of days so it might help other people.

Comment: updated my answer with SPA approuch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this to my template:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: Url }">View</a>
```

And this to my Foo object:

```
public class Foo : FooBase {
    public long FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public string Url {
        get {
            return string.Format("/foo/{0}/{1}", FooId, FooName
        }
    }
}
```

The cons:

- Painfully scalable.

The pros:

- Simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

**This does not answer question, but I will keep it here because it shows how you can do it for a more SPA like approuch.**

If you are looking to move navigation to client check out Durandal or my light weight SPA engine
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo

**Old answer before question was updated**

You have to do this from your model (Which is a good thing because it should not be done in the view)

Let your subview model take the parameters as constructor arguments

```
MyViewModel = function() {
   this.subView = ko.observable();
};

MyViewModel.prototype = {
   loadSubView: function() {
      this.subView(new SubViewModel(this.params));
   }
};
```

edit: Tip test this lib for templating
http://jsfiddle.net/hwTup/

Comment: How this subview stuff answers the question? The OP wants to combine the server side razor code `@Html.RouteLink` with the client side KO view model properties, so how is your answer a solution for this?

Comment: He wants a knockout equivalent, if not, question needs to be more clear

Comment: This answer is interesting @Anders but how would Esteban use the URL that is dynamic in nature? I think there is something like `computed` in KO. Can he use that? Maybe you can change your answer and reflect that for a better answer.